# Google Play Services on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to upload files directly from Android Wear to Google Drive using Google Play Service and Wear's WiFi. The question is that does Google Play Services supports Android Wear, particularly Google+ sign in and Google Drive?

**Updated**

I started with GPS 9.2.1, following message loged

```
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.service.START on com.google.android.gms
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.signin.service.START on com.google.android.gms
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.drive.ApiService.START on com.google.android.gms
E/Recordr: onConnectionFailed message: null, has solution false                       /com.anttek.soundrecorder.gd.GoogleDrive.onConnectionFailed(GoogleDrive.java:80)
```

Upgrade to GPS 9.4.

```
W/AuthSignInClient: Could not launch sign in Intent. Google Play Service is probably being updated...
I/Recordr: Sign in fail, Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null} /com.anttek.soundrecorder.gd.GoogleDrive.onConnectionFailed(GoogleDrive.java:80)
```

GPS on Wear version 9.4.52

Answer (score 1):

For the question does Google Play service supports Android wear? The answer is yes, but for Google+ and Google Drive particularly? I think as of now, it is not. I found here in this link the list of Google apps that will work with Android Wear, and Google Drive is not here. I also found your post in the [Google+ community](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/communities/113381227473021565406), one of the community also says that Drive and Google+ is not supported in Android Wear. But, someone says that Google Drive Support would be an awesome feature for 2.0, but He is not sure. So for this Android Wear 2.0, you can check [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-wear-20-developer-preview.html) and this [link](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/index.html) the feature and the upgrade that they added. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks KENdi, there is no indication that Google Auth and Google Drive are supported in Android Wear 2.0. Stay tuned.